# Operadores abreviados, qué retorna (!false)?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Es cierto que en una condición, la expresión que esté adentro se puede evaluar rápidamente de dos maneras, si está sola (expresión) es porque evalua si dicha condición existe, o es verdadera; y si se le agrega un signo de admiración al principio (!expresión), evalua si ésta es falsa, teniendo en cuenta ésto, la condición `!false` retorna **true** o **false** ?

Comment: el valor inicial es un booleano `false` entonces al agregar al inicio el operador `!` de negación estarías inviertiendo el valor original de operador `boolean` para pasar de `false` a `true`, pudieras agregar al ejercicio esto `console.log(!!!!false)` para ver como se comporta y va alternando el booleano obtenido (caray cuantas veces usé `booleano`) en este comentario XD

Comment: De la documentación de [MSDN Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) cito: El operador **NOT (!) lógico:   
Regresa false si su único operando puede convertirse a true; de lo contrario, regresa true.**

Answer (score 1):

No todas las expresiones son verdaderas. El operador not lógico (`!`) lo que hace es negar la expresión. `false` es una expresión que evalúa a falso, por lo que si lo niegas (`!false`) tendrás una condición verdadera.

`null` es otra condición que evalúa a falso. Por lo que `!null` evalúa a verdadero. Lo mismo pasa con `undefined`, `0`, `-0`, `NaN`, y `''` (string vacío).

De la documentación sobre el objeto [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Boolean#Par.C3.A1metros):

> El valor inicial del objeto `Boolean`. El valor es convertido a un valor `boolean`, si es necesario. Si se omite el valor o es 0, -0, null, false, `NaN`, undefined, o la cadena vacía (""), el objeto tiene un valor inicial de false. Todos los demás valores, incluyendo cualquier objeto o la cadena "`false`", crea un objeto con el valor inicial de true.

Objetos Boolean con valor inicial falso:

```
bNoParam = new Boolean();
bZero = new Boolean(0);
bNull = new Boolean(null);
bEmptyString = new Boolean("");
bfalse = new Boolean(false);
```

Objetos Boolean con valor inicial verdadero:

```
btrue = new Boolean(true);
btrueString = new Boolean("true");
bfalseString = new Boolean("false");
bSuLin = new Boolean("Su Lin");
```

Answer (score 0):

El signo ! solo debe usarse cuando lo que sigue es una expresión  Booleana, es decir true o false , en terminos practicos se usa para una negracion y es exactamente lo mismo que hacer un "== false". Mira este simple ejercicio

```
true  // true 
false // false
!false // true
!true  // false
!true == false // true
!false == true //true
```

Nota: true y false en si misma ya son una expresión booleana por ejemplo puedes hacer true== true   o True = false, etc.

Comment: creo que una explicación complementaría bien tu aporte, pues solo responder con código no deja en claro el concepto

Comment: gracias, editaré esta respuesta ;)